# BuddyPress User Profile Menu

Tags: hooks, buddypress, conditional-tags, profiles, conditional-content

I need to show BuddyPress menu item just specific roles and hide all other users.
I have 2 user roles like subscriber and author.
For example; I want to show my friends only to the authors and to me. None of the other subscribers can see.

I can hide menu items with this code in functions.php ;

```
function bp_remove_nav_item() {
    global $bp;    
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'buddyblog' );
    }
add_action( 'wp', 'bp_remove_nav_item' );
```

How can I edit this for excepting to me and the authors ?

Answer (score 2):

I solved it with my own effort.

```
function bp_remove_nav_item() {
    global $bp;
    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];
    if($role_name==='administrator'){
    bp_core_remove_nav_item( 'buddyblog' );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp', 'bp_remove_nav_item' );
```

This code delete blog menu for administrator.